# How to pass Boolean OR int from PHP to Android

Tags: php, android, http, boolean, int

I've been writing a program that relies a lot on passing strings from PHP to android; I use entityutils.toString to pass that information to my app.

However, I now need to pass a Boolean from PHP to android. Obviously the entityutils.toString tool will not be any good. I'm having real trouble identifying the correct methods for this in my online searches.

Can any of you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an encoding such as JSON that distinguishes between integers and boolean values.

Comment: I've actually used this method before - but am going on little sleep and completely forgot. This is the method I can use - thanks (although you guys don't mess around with the -1s)

Answer (score 0):

Change the boolean to true/false and the int, to regular int. 1 (true) is the SAME as 1 integer. you could also append the letter b or i to the beginning?